# I cannot create OAuth 2.0 client ID on google cloud platform

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, google-oauth

I am trying to create OAuth 2.0 client ID for Apps Script API and getting the following message:

> "The request failed because one of the fields of the resource is invalid"

I have tried to solve with many permission trials with no success.
I am the owner of the project, so theoretically shouldn't have an issue.

Any idea how to solve that?

[image: credentials add screen]

[image: error message]

Comment: This is probably the case where sending a feedback to Google support team will be beneficial - they usually respond well to what has a log tracking number even for non-gsuite accounts. That said, please, provide some info on how your Oauth consent screen looks like (remove personal info, but please, retain subdomain structure for authorized domains, for example - sub.base.com)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the issue is specific to my project. I asked another developer to check it with a different project and the same error message was fired. I think that this is a Google issue.

I created Desktop app OAUTH 2.0 and was able to use it with apps script with no issues.
I am using the following API with these credentials:

```
SCOPES = (
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity', # Allows read and write access to the Drive Activity API.
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts', # access to apps script
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
)
```

Comment: Could you please escalate the issue to Google via "feedback" option and update the answer when they respond - it may help some people be assured that they are not responsible for the issue?